# Polymer 1.x: Polymer template for Firebase?

Tags: templates, firebase, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm looking for a "live code" repository (e.g., jsBin, jsFiddle, CodePen, plunkr, etc.) **template** useful for sandboxing (i.e., "posting") Polymer questions about the `firebase-collection` or `firebase-document`.

In other words, I'm building a Polymer app using a Firebase backend and I need a template to use for posting questions to this site.

For example, [here is the template I use to post Polymer questions](http://jsbin.com/sitomotoji/edit?html,output). Is there one that anyone knows of that can also support questions about the `firebase-collection` or `firebase-document` elements? *(I'm guessing this would require a firebase with public read/write access.)*

http://jsbin.com/sitomotoji/edit?html,output

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!---- >
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  Toggle below/above as backup when server is down
  <!---->
  <base href="https://polygit2.appspot.com/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>

<dom-module id="x-element">

<template>
  <style></style>

<paper-button on-tap="_handleTap">Click Me</paper-button>

</template>

<script>
  (function(){
    Polymer({
      is: "x-element",
      properties: {
      },
      _handleTap: function() {
        alert('User clicked me!');
      },
    });
  })();
</script>

</dom-module>

<x-element></x-element>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/xojoxubigi/edit?html,output

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!---- >
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <!---- >
  Toggle below/above as backup when server is down
  <!---->
  <base href="https://polygit2.appspot.com/components/">
  <!---->
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="firebase-element/firebase-collection.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>

<dom-module id="x-element">

<template>
  <style></style>

  <p>
    <paper-button on-tap="_handleClick">Click Me</paper-button>
  </p>
  <!---->
    <firebase-collection
      location="https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs"
      data="{{dinosaurs}}"></firebase-collection>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[dinosaurs]]" as="dinosaur">
      <div>
        [[dinosaur.height]]
      </div>
    </template>
  <!---->

</template>

<script>
  (function(){
    Polymer({
      is: "x-element",
      _handleClick: function() {
        console.log('You clicked me!');
      }
    });
  })();
</script>

</dom-module>

<x-element></x-element>

</body>
```